# Add context parameters to Talend job in Tac via API without actually running it

Tags: java, talend, context-param

This seems to be a weird situation, but I want to know (have googled in Talend forums and their [API docs](https://help.talend.com/reader/oYf9gKhmYrkWCiSua4qLeg/SLiAyHyDTjuznLR_F~MiQQ), but nothing) if it is possible to set the context parameters for an already deployed task in TAC *without actually running it*.

I say that last part because I already know how and have the ability to run a specified job with the right context parameter values, but that's actually a step further than I need to go.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the metaservlet API-s updateTask command. Although the documentation does not lists that it can modify the contexts but it can. Just keep in mind that the context json section shouldn't be the last one, because the parsing they use will not work if the last tag is context. So basically do it the same way as you would do with runTask command.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing!!!! Thanks will make your answer as official.

Answer (score 0):

default context parameters are stored inside

```
<job-name>/items/<namespace>/process/<job-name>_<revision>.item
```

inside of a built project

Comment: Right - when you load a task to TAC it has the values of the context you set in the job, if you set any. However, in my case I need them to be completely dynamic so I need to update them every time I upload a different instance of a job. Hope that made sense.

I think I actually got it with the updateTask API call. It's a bit wonky and didn't think it would work with jobs pulled from Nexus, but it seemed to do the trick!