# How can I pass context params using talend api?

Tags: talend

I'm trying to automate talend job executions using the Talend API but I'm getting an error when I try to pass the context params using the api.

The json I'm encoding to 64 is the following:

```
JSON='{ "actionName":"runTask", "authPass": "TalendPass", "authUser": "name@example.com", "jvmParams": [ "-Xmx256m" , "-Xms64m" ], "contextParams": ["host_mysql_db01": "failed", "database_analytics": "testing.it"],"mode": "synchronous", "taskId": 43}'
```

Error message:

```
{"error":"Expected a ',' or ']' at character 172","returnCode":2}
```

I found another stackoverflow issue [Add context parameters to Talend job in Tac via API without actually running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301736/add-context-parameters-to-talend-job-in-tac-via-api-without-actually-running-it/52387486) but he doesn't say how he pass it and I cannot reply with a comment asking how he did it

The real talend api call is:

```
wget -O file http://localhost:8080/org.talend.administrator/metaServlet?$JSON_ENCODED
```

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the json your are passing to the metaservlet is not valid json. You can check it with an online validator like http://jsonlint.com.
You are specifying the `contextParams` attribute as an array, but that syntax is not valid in json. An array can contain either a list of values (like `jvmParams`) or objects (which can themselves contain arrays). Here's an [example](https://restfulapi.net/json-array/).
Moreover, according to [Talend reference](https://help.talend.com/reader/zG7iZ5VB0XkesgeKP4qk_A/do9Z8lpC4HPfbVQ11dXCOA), the attribute should be called "`context`" and must be an object instead of an array, like so:

```
"context":{"varname1": "varvalue", "varname2": "varvalue2"}
```

Comment: Thanks @iMezouar I got it working. I found the context value in the talend documentation but it didn't show how we should pass the params.